# Is there anything like a badge that I can programmatically place on a user's page?

Tags: facebook, image, iframe, feed

I would like to be able to place a permanent image or better yet and iframe in a user's facebook page.  The image or iframe would be reloaded from my website every time the page is viewed so that it contains the most recent data.

Can I do this?  If not, how close can I get? (For instance, posting things in the User's info page, or in their feeds.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used to be able to do this using Profile Boxes, but there's no similar functionality that currently exists to do what you're describing.